# Drag Element in Div . Dont drag in itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following div :

```
<div id="Cc" style="height: 40px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black" class="ui-sortable ui-droppable">
                </div>
```

I've successfully made connection with 2 draggable ul's that create a new horizontal list within this div,and when i click an element from list it gets removed :

```
 $("#Cc").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var a = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
                ts = "";
                if (dlistCc.length > 0)
                    ts = ",";
                var checkExists = document.getElementById("Id_" + a);
                if (checkExists) {
                    alert("Already there !");
                } else {
                    dlistCc.push(a);
                    var listElem = "<li  id=\"Id_" + a + "\"onclick=\"RemFromList('" + a + "_" + name + "_" + "#Cc" + "');\" style=\"font-weight:bold;margin-top: 1px;list-style-type: none;display:inline; margin-bottom: 3px; cursor:pointer; font-size: 11px; color:Black; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;  margin-left:2px; width:150px;\"><a>" + ts + $.trim($(ui.draggable).text()).replace(/\s(?=\s)/g, '') + "</a></li>";
                    $("#Cc").append(listElem);

                }
                NamesCc = NamesCc + listElem;
            }

        });
```

, but i have the following problem : I can drag element within my own div, and it duplicates the element . How can i prevent it ?

[image]
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

`var a = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');`

`var checkExists = document.getElementById("Id_" + a);`

There is a difference between these two lines, can you see it?

<sub>`"Id_" +`</sub>

Comment: It's not that . I can add elements from two lists : one is a regular user that has id formed by : "Id_ " + actual id. or groupId that is formed by : " G_ " + actual groupID. The code is fine ... I think it's all about a propriety i should set on the div to make it undraggable.

Comment: Then why won't you do that? Add a class `dropped` to it and disallow dropping elements that have that.

Comment: That's my issue :disallowing dropping elements for my div ? I want it to be droppable for other divs but i dont want it to be able to drag elements from itself. I've been looking for a valid solution via google , but nothing there.

Comment: @Noobsyke: Then do what I said in my previous comment, that solves your problem. If you add it to the `var listElem = "...";` line, it will only be put on the items in your drag container.